# Embed plugin into Custom Page Template

Tags: plugins, embed

I've created a new page type:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Pagina de Agenda
*/
?>


<?php get_header();?>

<?php $info_address = get_option('theme_info_address') ;?>



        <div id="content">


          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- END OF CONTENT -->
        <?php get_footer();?>
```

And the only thing I need, is to call [wcs] shortcode into content div... But It ain't working...

Already tried:

```
[wcs]

<?php echo do_shortcode('[wcs]'); ?>

do_shortcode('wcs')
```

None of them worked :s

I've seen a question about this here but didn't solve my problem yet...

Comment: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[wcs]'); ?>` is correct. (I tested it.) I can only assume that there is something wrong with your shortcode callback function or with the registration of the shortcode but you didn't post that code.

Comment: @s_ha_dum, thanks for your answer, take a look at my comments bellow \/

Comment: That is not a "comment" it is an "answer". Please edit your question to incorporate the additional information, and delete that answer-which-isn't-an-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something

```
is_page()
```

to output the page content:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

further reading about shortcodes
http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/

Comment: If I edit the page and add only [wcs], it works. But I need it to be added by default, simply by setting this specific page template (because who's gonna use this site has no tech knowledge)... I don't have to add a closure tag when I edit :s

Comment: It works like this: http://oi47.tinypic.com/zivdrs.jpg

I just need to add this [wcs] code by default on this page template :3

Comment: image is not working. show us the function code at funtions.php... that page-template what is intended to show? just one page, posts for the agenda? Show your content code... i think that was @s_ha_dum was asking for as well.

Comment: This is a schedule plugin: http://pulsarwebdesign.com/weekly-class-schedule - It isn't on functions.php - The page-template is as posted on the question /\ - I've fixed the image link now

Comment: The 3 first sentences are better placed as a comment in the Question. Finally, you mention `is_page()`, but it doesn't appear in the sample code... (¡?) :::: Check [this meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/185667).

Comment: Found this in the plugin files:
 `public static function addShortcode()
  {
    add_shortcode( 'wcs', array( 'WcsOutputController', 'wcsShortcodeCallback' ) );
  }`